# Whe the conjugate operator in $\mathbb{C}$ is a automorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, automorphism-group

$*: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$

$a^{*} = (xa)x^{-1}, \quad x \in \mathbb{H}$

Why *(conjugated) operation is a automorphism in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Use the link: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node5.html

Comment: For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, the map $a\mapsto zaz^{-1}$ is just the identity map, since $\mathbb{C}$ is an abelian group. Does it help?

Comment: but $x \in \mathbb{H}$ and i forgot a information: $x^{2} = -1$